# Failed social authentication using Laravel socialite

Tags: php, ios, authentication, oauth

When i login with facebook from mobile iphone5 iOS apps and it call laravel API to use socialite, I get this error:

GET [https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/me?access_token=Access_token_here=name,email,gender,verified,link&appsecret_proof=secret_proof_here`](https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/me?access_token=Access_token_here=name,email,gender,verified,link&appsecret_proof=secret_proof_here%60) resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:

{"error":{"message":"Unsupported get request.","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"fbtrace_id_code (truncated...)

I also tried to send this request from Browser or Postman and it works returning Json with user detail as following:

{
"name": "My Facebook Name",
"email": "email@mail.com",
"id": "personal_facebook_id"
}

I also tried to login with another device iOS (Iphone 6) and it works.